# Using encoded polylines in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am having trouble when trying to use encoded polylines in OpenLayers 3.  I have an external source providing the encoded strings, but when I try to convert them into a feature and add them to a vector source, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ua' of undefined
```

Here is the current code I am using:

```
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: "SKL Tile Server",
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
            url: "https://placeholder/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            crossOrigin: null
        })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        name: "polylines",
        source: vectorSource
    })
];

map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'report_map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(
            [-118.014670, 45.35724], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'),
        zoom: 10
    })
})

var addPolylineToMap = function (encoded_line, line_style) {

    var line = new ol.format.Polyline().readGeometry({
        source: encoded_line,
        options: {
            dataProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
            featureProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:900913')
        }
    });
    line.setStyle(line_style);
    vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature(line));
    return line;
};
```

Admittedly, I am quite new to OpenLayers 3--but I have searched extensively and can't seem to find any examples of using encoded polylines in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var addPolylineToMap = function (encoded_line, line_style) {

    var format = new ol.format.Polyline({
        //factor: 1e6
    });
    var line = format.readGeometry(encoded_line, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:900913'
    });

    var feature = new ol.Feature({geometry: line});
    feature.setStyle(line_style);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

    return line;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved this issue.  Can you recommend any resources for learning OpenLayers 3 beyond the official documentation?  I don't know how I would have ever arrived at your solution from the resources I've found.

Comment: My source has been the docs, I read it for every issue. Ahh, and of course, the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples), check all of them, even if you don't need that specific solution.